# LINQ Query to filter DTO

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have an array...and I need to exclude all the items in this array of string from the `masterList.customField` as shown below

```
string[] excludeItem = {"a","b","c"};

CustomDTO[] masterList = service.LoadMasterList();

masterList.Where(c=> masterList.customField NOT IN excludeItem
```

How do I achieve the NOT IN part above?

Comment: using the suggested solution you should think of keeping your excludedItem in a HashSet rather than an array. for a low number the array might be faster but in the average case HashSet.Contains will be faster than Array.Contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming customField is a string:

```
masterList.Where(c => !excludeItem.Contains(c.customField));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, as a LINQ query:

```
var x = from c in masterList
        where !excludedItem.Contains(c.CustomField)
        select c;
```